# Ways to present text for iPhone app user

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, text

I'm working on my iPhone app and I'm a bit newbie with iOS development. I had to show some text information for user over all application. Plus i'll have a "Library" part, which will be kind of wiki page. So it'll be more or less formated text with some images in my app.

I wondering, **how to implement it?**

Its a lot of ways to do it, from "*just make an photo of formatted text + images, and put it in to*`UIImageView`" to using different standart UI elements (`UILabel`, `UIImageView`, `UITextView`, `UIScrollView`, `UIWebView` etc.) or even creating custom.

---

I'm thinking about using `UIWebView` + local HTML files (especially for "Library"), but I'm not sure. I think it's much easy to format text and images presented in HTML. And navigation can be easy realized with links. Isnt'it?

I never worked with such stuff, completely have no idea of **possible issues with different ways of presenting formatted text**. It would be nice to hear about **advantages of all kinds of methods**!

Comment: What have you tried in terms of code and what is not working for you? I am sorry but I am just lost reading your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to solve your task is to use `UIWebView`. There're no any disadvantages of such approach. You'll be able format text as you wish and create any complexity. And the most benefit is customisation: you could correct anything in your text without painful relocation of labels/images and so on. I'm definitely vote for `UIWebView`.

You could also try a `CoreText` for this. But it's much harder to implement and still need some formatted text source. You will create your own copy of `UIWebView` with reduced functionality and tons of bugs. I wouldn't recommend this way.

The last possible way is to create your own element based on standard UI controls. I think it's the worst solution. You'll be ended up with a slow enormous monster and I don't believe you'll be satisfied with results you get.